# Python mysql "Unread result found" error when no rows available

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I'm new to the combination of python and MySql (through mysql.connector), so I'm hoping the resolution to my problem is straightforward. I have an application that uses one cursor to traverse a long table, with a few preparedCursors that query other tables as the rows in the main table are processed. The latter are designed to return a single row (enforced using "limit 1"). At a certain row in the main table (always the same one, regardless of whether it's the 4000th or the 100000th one encountered), one of the prepared queries fails with "Unread results found" error. When I try, just before the error occurs, to see if there are in fact more results, using fetchone(), I get a result of None. So where are these unread results, and how can I get rid of them?
Another thing I don't understand (and possibly related) is why the .rowcount attribute of the cursor keeps counting up - every time the query returns a result (always a single row), the rowcount increases by one, while it stays the same if no rows are found. Do I need to somehow reset the cursor between queries?
Here are some relevant bits of my code:

```
my=mydb.cursor(buffered=True)
lastipq=mydb.cursor(cursor_class=MySQLCursorPrepared)  #same whether I use buffered or not
lastipqs="select hex(ip),scan,stretch from iphistory where domid=%s order by scan desc limit 1"
i=430000
while i<ndoms:
    my.execute("select domid from olddom limit "+str(i)+",100000") 
    for r in my:
        domid=r[0]
        rc=lastipq.rowcount
        try:
            if domid==2984827:   #this is the row where the error always occurs
               print("rowcount before",lastipq.rowcount)
               rr=lastipq.fetchone()
               print(rr)
            lastipq.execute(lastipqs,(domid,))
            rr=lastipq.fetchone()
        except:
            print("Error processing domain",domid,"rows",rc)
            rr=lastipq.fetchone()
            print(rr)
```

Output:

```
rowcount before 4330
None
Error processing domain 3037905 rows 4331
None
```

Comment: What statement actually raises the exception?  The `execute()` or the `fetchone()`?

Comment: The execute statement